# Pairing Apple Wireless Keyboard to Mac Pro not running macOS

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, freenas

I'm running FreeNAS (basically customized version of FreeBSD) on a Mac Pro. I would like to use the Apple Wireless Keyboard vs having to tie up a USB port and deal with a corded keyboard.

I do not have a macOS drive on this Mac, but I could remove existing drives, stick a spare macOS drive in there, pair the keyboard and put all the drives back. However, I don't wanna go through all that trouble unless I am sure it'll work.

So, can I pair an Apple Wireless Keyboard with my Mac Pro in macOS, but then remove macOS and book into FreeNAS and it be able to word?

Comment: The BT stack is built into FreeBSD (I can't speak for what FreeNAS did)  Have a look at the [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-bluetooth.html) to see if you can pair the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks @Allan, what I'm trying to avoid is trying to pair with the OS. It seems it might be possible to avoid this since you can pair a keyboard, then boot into recovery and still have access to the keyboard, as if the keyboard is paired with Mac itself, not the OS.

Comment: It has to be.  If it didn't you wouldn't be able to reset NVRAM or your SMC